# How to build only a specific project with DevOps Pipelines

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-integration

Is this possible to build only a single project and its dependencies specified in a pipeline script?

---

If I have a Visual Studio Solution with multiple projects, and websites, and I want to build and publish only a specific website and it's dependencies, how could it be done when using DevOps Pipelines, so it does not build the whole solution, but only the required projects for that specific website.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want to only build a single project in your solution, you could use the [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) in Azure Devops Pipelines and then point it to the project you want to build.
Another way would be to in your VS solution to edit the Configuration Properties. In the Configuration Manager you can create a Configuration called Single_Project or something like that and then in the properties select which projects to build when using that configuration. Then when you use the [VS Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops) and specify the configuration you created for your build.